# Using the right encoding for csv file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, encoding, decoding

I wrote a function that takes one variable, `file`, which is a big `.csv` document. I get the following error immediately after calling the function for one specific file (the file is in German):

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 4: invalid continuation byte`

The system's default encoding is `utf-8`, but if I `open('C:/Users/me/Desktop/data/myfile.csv')`, the output is:

`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/me/Desktop/data/myfile.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`.

Using `file.decode('cp1252').encode('utf8')` doesn't work since `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`, so I tried:

```
for decodedLine in open('C:/Users/me/Desktop/data/myfile.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1252'):
    line = decodedLine.split('\t')
```

but `line` is a list object and I can't `.encode()` it.

How can I make `.csv` files that have a different encoding readable?

Comment: What language is the file?

Comment: @gsa German, but it's not the only file containing ä,ü,ö etc. that I processed.

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` Put this in the first line of your file.

Comment: @gsa Sorry for the naive question, but does this need to be put in the beginning of the script, when importing all the modules, or in the first line within the function? I tried both and I get the same error.

Comment: Did you try to set `encoding` parameter when you open the file? Something like this: `open(..., encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Do you know the encoding of your `csv` file? It looks like your file is not `utf-8` based on the `UnivodeDecodeError` you get.

Comment: If you want to encode/decode line data you must do it BEFORE splitting it by tabs (which is where you get the list from):
`line = decodedLine.split('\t')` 
The `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line refers to the encoding of your Python code not the files opened by that code so if you don't use any special characters in your code you don't need it.
Also, you might want to use the `csv` module for handling CSV files.

Comment: @norok2, its encoding is `'cp1252'`. @Alperen, how do I set the `encoding` parameter in the function (such that the function is applied to the encoded file)? I tried with .decode().encode() as said above, but it didn't work.

Comment: Once the encoding is known and the file is open, you don't need to do more than that to read the data. So, what exactly is your question then? Or, alternatively, why do you want to `.encode()` your `decodedLine` (whose name may be deceiving, its just a `line` with type `str` and you could `.encode()` if you like.. decoding is for binary data, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) for more info on `str` and `bytes`).

Comment: @n.mathfreak Stop thinking about `.decode()` and `.encode()`. You don't need those functions at all. Open the text file with the correct `encoding` parameter and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `csv` file with `cp1252` encoding.
If that is the case, all you have to do is open the file with the right encoding.
As far as the `csv` is concerned, I would use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) module from the standard library.
Alternatively, you may want to look into a more specialized library like [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Anyway, to parse your `csv` you could do just:

```
import csv

with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='cp1252') as file_obj:
    # adjust the parameters according to your file, see docs for more
    csv_obj = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    for row in csv_obj:
        # row is a list of entries
        # this would print all entries, separated by commas
        print(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: When opening files for the `csv` module, always set `newline=''`, because the csv module transparently handles all types of line endings correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit confused about applying the function to the file with the right encoding. Do I have to use `new_file = ', '.join(row)` as the data I'm working with now?

Comment: What do you mean by that? the `csv_obj` will basically let you iterate through the rows and you will get a `list` of entries/cells. What will you do with that is totally up to you. In that sense, you do not have to do `', '.join(row)` if you don't need a line of the `.csv` file as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest  to try to open it with pandas using the `read.csv` function with different encodings until it shows properly. Try encoding:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:yourpath',encoding = "latin-1")
```

If this doesn't work try similar encodings until you find it.

Then you can use the correct encoding as you want.